# Why does Math.Log crash only inside my for loop?

Tags: ruby, for-loop, logarithm

I have the below code

```
A = 1.0
B = 0.20
N = 8.0
for i in 1..Total
  t = Maxt * rand
  x = A * Math.cos(t) / (Math.log(B*Math.tan(t/(2*N))))
  y = A * Math.sin(t) / (Math.log(B*Math.tan(t/(2*N))))
end
```

If I comment out the For loop it executes fine and produces 1 of the results I want. If I don't comment out the for loop, it generates the below. I am a newbie with Ruby and am mainly curious why it only breaks when the for loop is present.

```
rubyfile.rb:22:in `log': Numerical argument out of domain - log (Errno::EDOM)
    from rubyfile.rb:22
    from rubyfile.rb:20:in `each'
    from rubyfile.rb:20
```

Comment: How are `Total` and `Maxt` defined?

Comment: You can speed up the for loop if yuo don't calculate `Math.log(B*Math.tan(t/(2*N)))` twice. This gives you the opportunity to print out `B*Math.tan(t/(2*N))` to see what value you put into that log.

Comment: @Matchu Total and Maxt are arbitrary numbers that I specify to limit the number of generated coordinates and to restrict the spiral's length and windings.

Comment: @hans Thank you, I hadn't noticed that yet. But will definitely remember that when I verify my equation was successful and I go to implement this.

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote? I would like to avoid whatever mistake I have made in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Math.log` represents the logarithm function, which is undefined for negative numbers. `Math.tan`, however, represents the tangent function, which can return negative numbers. So, if `Math.tan` comes out to a negative number, the `Math.log` will tell you that its argument is "out of domain", meaning that there is no logarithm for that number.

I'm betting the fact that your input is random means that, when you loop, you are far more likely to get that error than if you just run the script once. If you were the remove the loop then run the script multiple times, I bet you'd get that error eventually.

Find out why your math involves negative numbers when it shouldn't, and you're good to go :)

Comment: This makes total sense. I have forgotten a lot of my Trigonometry and various other mathematics. Well now it is time to go over the original equation to figure out where I botched the conversion from polar to rectangular.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

`B*Math.tan(t/(2*N)))` will take negative values and log is undefined for `x < 0`. As the error states, you're out of domain.